# Quickbooks Online API: Create Account step says that 'Name already exists', but a check for the name just before reports zero results

Tags: api, quickbooks-online

I have a solution that integrates with QBOnline, and exports Invoices to QBO. This process that has been around for a while, and usually works pretty well. But this time, it's giving an odd error.

It checks a number of things before getting to the line items: Customer, Production, Project, etc. Then for this one Invoice, when it starts to process the line items, it also pre-checks some things. If things don't exist in QBO, then it will create them.

In this case, it tries to retrieve the 'Account', to see if it already exists.   Query:

```
    ?query=select * from account where Name = 'Audio:Film:Editorial'
```

Result: `None found`

So this process then tries to create an Account (data being submitted is at the bottom of the cURL options):

cURLOptions:

```
-D $dump_header 
-X POST 
-H "Authorization: Bearer eyJl...VGE4w" 
-H "Accept: application/json" 
-H "Content-Type: application/json" 
-d {"AccountType":"Income","Name":"Audio:Film:Editorial"}
```

Result:

```
{"Fault":{"Error":[{"Message":"Duplicate Name Exists Error","Detail":"The name supplied already exists. : Id=345","code":"6240"}],"type":"ValidationFault"},"time":"2023-02-13T16:36:44.868-08:00"}
```

So the response to this query is that the Account already exists...but didn't it just test for and was told that the Account did NOT exist?

Any hints on what is causing the error message?  Or what I need to look at under the hood to see what existing values might be causing it to trip up?

Comment: Updated my original posting to reflect the correct query syntax.

Answer (score 0):

The default behavior of the QuickBooks APIs is to *not return inactive objects*.

My bet here is that when you're doing your query against the API, you're just asking for a list of accounts... and only getting back the *Active* ones. What you should be doing is asking for the list of *all* accounts, regardless of status.

I don't know what this is, because this *is not an API call you can send to QuickBooks* (check your code - you probably transform that to something that QuickBooks can understand somewhere else in your code):

```
 {"api":"QuickBooks","companyID":"1 - MyCompany, Ltd","query":{"fieldName":"accountName","object":"account","searchValue":"Audio:Film:Editorial"},"username":"Test Dev"}
```

But what you should be sending to QuickBooks is a query like this to get the active and inactive accounts:

```
  SELECT * FROM Account WHERE Active IN (true, false)
```

Comment: Ah, great point.  I'll give it a review and see what results I get.  Yes, you are correct about the query being altered into a SELECT statement later on.

Comment: So I did some testing, and have a slightly better view:  The account DOES exist, and it IS curretly active.  Problem is that it is a child relationship to another account.  So the 'Name' is just "Editorial", but the 'FullyQualifiedName' is "Audio:Film:Editorial".  I'm not sure if the default API search is supposed to auto-parse the full name "Audio:Film:Editorial" into it's parent/child syntax; or if this query has been searching against the wrong field for a long time.  The 'create account' process apparently does parse the input string "Audio:Film:Editorial" into parent/child sub-objects.